# Choosing a Server for CSV import of 400k Products

Tags: mysql, wordpress, csv, batch-file

I am in need of some help in understanding and selecting a server to use for a website.  If somebody has a CSV file of 400,000 products that they need to import into a website, what would be the best server to handle the load and minimize timeouts when uploading?

I'm assuming it would be possible to utilize Wordpress (with MySQL), WooCommerce and WP All Imports to import the CSV file of products.  To help with the upload process, I figured it would be best to create 40 batches of 10,000, products and upload them batch by batch.

Does this sound possible? Any thoughts? Thanks!

Comment: This isn't about programming. This belongs on [SuperUser](http://superuser.com/).

Comment: If your web server is running on IIS, you could use the ADODB provider Jet 4.0 driver to query the CSV data as database records.  There's a [vbscript example here](http://nerds-central.blogspot.com/2008/01/importing-and-exporting-csv-files-from.html) showing an import to MS SQL from CSV.